# I want delete serializer's content to show

Tags: python, django

I want delete serializer's content to show.I am using Django Rest Framework.I am making a system return Json of serializers.Furthermore,I did not want to show user_id data. I wrote in views.py

```
class InfoViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def update(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = UserInfo.objects.get(pk=kwargs['id'])

        data = request.data
        info_serializers = InfoSerializer(obj, data = data)

        if info_serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            info_serializers.save()
            del info_serializers.data['user_id']
            return JsonResponse(info_serializers.data)
```

Now all son data is shown.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: try by adding `info_serializers.save()`  after delete statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in the serializers which fields you want to include or exclude in the response:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

look for : Specifying which fields to include

hope this helpes

Comment: thank you for your comments.I did not want to show user_id of Json only accessing update method.So,I cannot write the codes of restriction in Serializers.In this case,what should I do?

Comment: then copy `info_serializers.data` to new dict and delete user_id from it and pass that dict to return

Comment: I wrote `new_info_serializers = copy.copy(info_serializers)
            del new_info_serializers.data["user_id"]
            print(new_info_serializers.data)` but user_id is remained in dictionary.How should I do?

Comment: like what rasel said below - pop the key :)

Answer (score 0):

First Clone the object into a new variable and then pop the key.

`if info_serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            info_serializers.save()
            import copy
            new = copy.deepcopy(info_serializers.data)
            new.pop('user_id', None)
            return JsonResponse(new)`